# Subquerying in Django

Tags: mysql, django, orm

I have a Django 1.9 project implementing small chat app. All messages from a certain recipient are grouped into dialogs, so the models are defined as follows:

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    # Some fields

class Message(models.Model):
    dialog = models.ForeignKey(Dialog, ...) 
    text = models.TextField()
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

My goal is to render a template with a table that renders dialogs. And for each dialog in the table, I need to see

1. the **number** of **unread messages** and
2. the text of the **last message**.

To illustrate, consider mock-data below:

Input:

```
id      dialog_id    message          is_read
1          1         Hello, sir        false
2          1         My name is        true
3          1         Jack              true
4          2         This site         false
5          2         is perfect        false
6          2         Cheers            false
```

Desired output:

```
dialog_id     last_message_in_dialog      unread_messages_count
    1                  Jack                         1 
    2                 Cheers                        3
```

In pure mysql, I would write a query like this:

```
select 
       a.dialog_id, 
       text as last_message_in_dialog,
       (select count(*) from message 
        where dialog_id = a.dialog_id and is_read = false) as unread_messages_count
from message a
where id in (select max(id) from message group by dialog_id)
```

In Django terms, I have the code below:

```
max_id_qs = Message.objects.\
                    values('dialog__id').\
                    annotate(max_id = Max('id'),).values('max_id')

qs = Message.objects.filter(id__in = max_id_qs).\
                     values('dialog__id', 'text')
```

This code serves well to fetch the last message in each dialog. However, the problem is that I can't figure out how to implement the subquery `(select count(*) from message where dialog_id = a.dialog_id and is_read = false)` in Django. Maybe my total approach with `max_id_qs`is wrong, and there's more elegant and clear way to implement the query in Django ORM?
I've spent an entire day trying to solve this issue. help me please !

Answer (score 0):

This will work :-

```
allDistinctIdWithNotReadMsg = 
   Message.objects.filter(is_read=False).values('id').annotate(the_count=Count('is_read',distinct('id')))

for ids in allDistinctIdWithNotReadMsg:
    lastMsg = Message.objects.filter(dialog_id=ids['id']).order_by("-id")[0]
    for msg in lastMsg:

        print ids['id'] ,msg.message,ids['the_count']
```